# Call a child class method from a parent class variable without using instanceof or casting

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 4 classes

```
public class User {
    private Account account;

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Account {
    private double balance;
    private String password;
    private String userName;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private Provider provider;
// some getters and setters
    
}
```

```
public class BankAccount extends Account {
 
        // this not in the parent class
    private String accountNumber;

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    
    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber ;
    }
}
```

```
public class WalletAccount extends Account {

}
```

How I redesign this to make like this

```
Account account = new BankAcccount() ;
account.getAccountNumber() ;
```

> without using `instanceof` or casting like
>
> ```
> ((BankAccount) account)getAccountNumber() ;
> ```

Redesign the classes to allow call of the `BankAccount` methods without using `instanceof` or casting using design patterns or add more classes any approach.

Comment: Can you add a new class/interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simple case you can add an `abstract` method to the parent class.

```
public abstract class Account {
    private double balance;
    private String password;
    private String userName;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private Provider provider;
// some getters and setters
    public abstract String getAccountNumber();
}
```

This makes an `accountNumber` property to be abstract. Every non-abstract subclass should implement the abstract method of `Account` class.

Then you can use

```
Account account = new BankAcccount() ;
account.getAccountNumber() ;
```

> without using `instanceof` or casting like
>
> ```
> ((BankAccount) account)getAccountNumber() ;
> ```

This is allowed because `abstract` methods can use [polymorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

---

Another way is to use interface to access the property of some subclass. Another subclass might not implement this interface if it doesn't have such property. When you need to access the property then you upcast to the interface without `instanceof`.

```
public interface AccountNumberAware {
  public String getAccountNumber();
}

public abstract class Account implements AccountNumberAware {
    private double balance;
    private String password;
    private String userName;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private Provider provider;
// some getters and setters

    // dummy implementation of interface
    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return null;
    }
    
}
public class BankAccount extends Account {
 
        // this not in the parent class
    private String accountNumber;

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    
    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber ;
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
Account account = new BankAcccount() ;
account.getAccountNumber() ;
```

Comment: but class WalletAccount doesn't have an Account Number

Comment: It must have an account number because it extends `Account` and it abstract. I have added `getAccountNumber()` to `Accout` and it is inherited by `WalletAccount`.

Comment: The account number which in BankAccount class it represent of the bank account number which in the provider
so wallet does't has a bank so it does't has bank account number

Comment: If it doesn't have an account number then it should *not* extend `Account`. This class provides a property `accountNumber`. So this number will have all subclasses. We cannot make this property inherited for specific classes, so it is inherited to all.

Comment: You have asked how to call a child method from the parent class without casting. It is only possible if the parent class has a virtual method overriden in the child class. You should have `getAcvountNumber()` both in `Account` and `BankAccount`. No matter how would you implement it but it should be overriden. Try to remove `abstract` from the method then `WalletAccount` would not have to implement it. The class variable belongs only to `BankAccount`, so it is not available to another child, but it's available to parent at runtime, because a parent is a child by instance.

Comment: You have not to cast the instance to child if parent has a virtual method which is overriden in the child. In polymorphism the virtual method is called by the instance regardless which type the instance belongs to and without downcasing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  There is no way to do this.  Only something of type `BankAccount` -- which would have to be cast to it -- can have `getAccountNumber()` called on it.

Comment: Even desgin patterns will not solve it ?

Comment: No.  If only `BankAccount` has the function `getAccountNumber`, then you can only call that function on a `BankAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you shouldn't expect *Account* to have a *getAccountNumber* method.

Try the following.

```java
abstract class Account {
    private double balance;
    private String password;
    private String userName;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private Provider provider;

    String getAccountNumber() {
        return 
            this instanceof BankAccount 
                ? ((BankAccount) this).getAccountNumber() 
                : null;
    }
}
```